# Java Spring max. size limit for upload

Tags: java, spring, upload-max-filesize

I tried to upload files to my controller.

This is the upper part pf my controller. It works till i reach i maximum request size of +- 2MB

```
> @RequestMapping(value = {"/runlocalfiles"}, method =
> RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
>     @ResponseBody
>     @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
>     public ResponseEntity run( HttpServletRequest request) {
>         String jsonBase64Files = request.getParameter("base64files");
>         String jsonChecks = request.getParameter("checks");
```

Error message in browser:

```
> Failed to load http://localhost:5001/runlocalfiles: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
> access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Error in Java console:

```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The multi-part request contained
> parameter data (excluding uploaded files) that exceeded the limit for
> maxPostSize set on the associated connector   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2893)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]...
```

I have tried to increase the upload size by adding new lines to the application.properties. Also tried to change -1 to e.g. 100MB

```
> spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size= -1
> spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size= -1
> spring.http.multipart.max-file-size = -1
> spring.http.multipart.max-request-size= -1
```

Any help is apriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i found a working solution. I need to combine your two solutions.

Adding this to the initial class:

```
// Set maxPostSize of embedded tomcat server to 10 megabytes (default is 2 MB, not large enough to support file uploads > 1.5 MB)
@Bean
EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() throws Exception {
    return (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) -> {
        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
            tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(
                    (connector) -> {
                        connector.setMaxPostSize(100000000); // 100 MB
                    }
            );
        }
    };
}
```

and this to the application properties:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,it's working for me,add this to the application properties:

```
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Spring Boot and embed tomcat, you can try this:

```
@SpringBootApplication  
public class SpringBootWebApplication {  

    //private int maxUploadFileSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);  
    }  


    //Tomcat large file upload connection reset  
    @Bean  
    public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbedded() {  

        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();  

        tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {  
            if ((connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>)) {  
                //-1 means unlimited  
                ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1);  
            }  
        });  

        return tomcat;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Using the code above i got:
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field base64files exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I followed through the following [spring boot file upload tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) and as mentioned in the tutorial, following properties worked perfectly for me:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=300MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=300MB
spring.http.multipart.enabled=false
```

Comment: If i use this within the application.properties the controller accept the request, but the content of the request is null.